# Does mac OS install process erase flashdrive data DURING the install?

Tags: install, bootable-disk

It's well-documented that creating an install drive erases the target medium, but what about later, *during* the install process ?

i.e. can I create a bootable flash installer, and *then* add files to it, knowing that a later use of the flash for an installation will not erase those files ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my experience you can indeed put files on a flash drive that you made to boot and install macOS. The install process only *reads* from the flash drive. So your utilities should be safe.

Comment: Thanks Steve -- this is the sort of question that only someone who has done a _lot_ of installs would be able to answer.